# PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in file

Tags: php

Помогите разобраться Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in file

```
<?=$arNewsFields["ID"]? __bxhref="/news/?ID=<?=$arNewsFields[">"><span class="imgwrap"><span class="img" style="background-image:url(<?=$imgFile?>
```

где ошибка?

Comment: `__bxhref="/news/?ID=<?=$arNewsFields[">">` -- это что такое?

Comment: Это кусок кода сайта на битриксе.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Да хоть на чем, очень сомневаюсь что это нормальный синтаксис для Битрикса `$arNewsFields[">">` -- что это за такой ключ у массива? Если у Вас в начале уже открыт PHP тег, почему Вы его открываете внутри дальше еще раз? `__bxhref=` навеврное должен быть строкой `'__bxhref="/news/?ID=' . $arNewsFields['some_key'] . '"'` и так далее.

Answer (score 1):

Предполагаю, что должно быть так. И посоветую изучить синтаксис языка и возможность его разметки

```
<a href="/news/?ID=<?=$arNewsFields["ID"]?>"><span class="imgwrap"><span class="img" style="background-image:url(<?=$imgFile?>);">
```